# Components not resize/move in window builder - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I used to work through `drag/drop window builder plugin in Eclipse` & it was working perfectly fine.

I left that project for couple of days & I did update the `Eclipse` afterwards. I notice now after releasing the components I am not able to `resieze/move components` at all on existing `JFrame/JPanel`, but if I create a new `JFrame` in some cases it wokrs & in most case it does not. I checked the updates & there are no more updates available.

Any Idea how can I fix this annoying & weird behaviour of `Eclipse`.

**Version:** 2023-12 (4.30.0)

**Build id:** 20231201-2043

Illustration is attached for more info.

[image]
TIA